# Change class IF dropdown and H2 contents match certain criteria with Animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

Looking to add a class with jQuery if two different scenarios are met

> 1) The `dropdown` equals acting or backstage
>
> 2) The membership fields contains "Non-member"
>
> **if both these are met I wish to pulse(animate) the Upgrade button using the added Animate.css class.**

I have a couple of the parts of a function, just having some trouble piecing them together to work:

```
($(this).val() == 'Acting' || $(this).val() == 'Backstage')
```

and

```
$("#member_status").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  if(value === 'Non-member'){
  $("#upgrade_member").css('display','block');
  }
});
```

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="member_welcome">Welcome to our membership site</h1>
    <h2 id="member_status">Non-member</h2>

    <select class="regular-text" name="interest" id="interest">
                <option value="not specified">Not Specified</option>
                <option value="Watching">Watching</option>
                <option value="Acting">Acting</option>
                <option value="Backstage">Backstage</option>
                <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
        </select>

    <div style="margin-top:20px">
    <button id="upgrade_member">Upgrade Membership</button>
    </div>

    <div id="example" class="animated infinite bounce" style="margin-top:100px;">EXAMPLE</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**[Here is the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zOpmnl5Rm6nhoF2tSDil?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#interest").change(function() {
  var membership = $("#member_status").text().toLowerCase().includes("non-member");
  var interest = $("#interest").val().toLowerCase();
  if (membership && (interest == "acting" || interest == "backstage")) {
    $("#upgrade_member").addClass("animated infinite pulse");
  } else {
    $("#upgrade_member").removeClass("animated infinite pulse");
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#interest").change();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bnu8aLbw/)

Comment: Works great this, but the interest field is already populated when the page loads. So it works if I *change* the dropdown but not when the pages loads

Comment: @merch89 You can simply call the change function as soon as the document DOM structure is ready. I just updated the answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class in your Non-member. For example,

```
<h2 id="member_status" class="myClass">Non-member</h2>
```

In JQuery,

```
(document).ready(function () {
 function myFunction()
  {
   var text = $('#interest :selected').text();
   If(text == "Acting" || text == "Backstage")
      {
       $(".myClass").each(function() {
       var value = $(this).text();
       if(value === 'Non-member'){
          //do whatever you want to do
       }
   }
 }}})
```

In dropdown change event call the function

```
$("#interest").change(function () {
    myFunction();
});
```

If it's helps you please dont forget to mark as answer.